# How do I find a specific item in the review queue?

Tags: discussion

I've recently passed the landmark 500 rep and can now review selected types of posts. I've tentatively been through about half a dozen so far, and was happy enough with what I was doing (including one that came back with a message saying it was just a test, and I'd passed!).

However, I reviewed one this morning and clicked on the question itself. It was a duplicate about automounting drives, so I marked it as such, then tried to go back to the review to mark it as done.

But I couldn't find the same question again. In fact, the queue was empty, so I guess somebody else came along and reviewed it while I was in the process.

So, my question is this. Assuming a non-empty queue, is there a way I can get back to a specific item for review?  (I think I've already learned to open the questions in new tabs)

And a follow-up question. Is there any way to mark an item in the review queue to say "I'm on with this", so we aren't duplicating effort? Or are multiple reviewers the aim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be able to find it through [your review log](https://askubuntu.com/users/304825/carl-h?tab=activity&sort=reviews). By extension, [this is probably the review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/395654) you're looking for.

There's no way to re-review something. You've reviewed it and that has shunted it from the first-post queue [onto the close queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/395671).

On the subject of a review lock (while you review something), [I have requested this before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221985/can-reviewers-have-reserved-time-when-theyre-reviewing-a-post), as have many prominent SE users (you'll see mine was closed as a dupe alongside a good dozen other questions). Nothing has been done to fix this yet.

---

The timeline of the actual question in question is a little more complicated than you can see. Still trying to work out why you couldn't go back to the review though... [The first-post review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/395680) (which was handled by ByteCommander in the end) was done ten minutes after you voted to close, you should have been able to review it.

[image]

Comment: It was [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/603085/ntfs-drive-shows-in-file-manager-but-need-to-mount-it-before-i-can-access-it) that I meant, and it doesn't appear in my review log at all - possibly because I didn't do anything with it?

Comment: @CarlH It doesn't appear as if flagging is tracked in the logs (at least I couldn't find it on my all actions tab...)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149869/lock-questions-in-the-review-queue-while-being-reviewed/252713#252713